# Can you install LXDE or XFCE without altering non-desktop aspects of Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, desktop-environments

I love Ubuntu, and I love the Unity desktop environment. But sometimes I just need to do something fast and I don't need the extra flash of Unity, or I just want a different look and feel for awhile. So in the past on Ubuntu I have tried installing LXDE or XFCE for any number of reasons through the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

and...

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

respectively. Afterward I would come to find that odd changes had been made to Ubuntu that I had not wanted: such as Plymouth changing from the standard Ubuntu logo to the Xubuntu/Lubuntu logo. I am aware that you can [manually change this back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172859/xubuntu-start-up-screen-but-im-running-normal-ubuntu); but my concern is that other things/settings might also be getting changed or added in the process.

So my main question is if there is some method of installing LXDE or XFCE, with only the absolute most necessary changes or additions to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both LXDE and XFCE ([LXDE](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lxde), [XFCE](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xfce4)) are in the universe repository.

So you can just install either of the two in place of the correspondent full environment:

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Comment: And neither or these packages cause the additional changes caused by the desktop packages?

Comment: @IanLantzy No, their correspondent full environments also install, for example, lots of applications (most of which are installed already in Unity, but still); compare them to the [`lubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lubuntu-desktop) package and to the [`xubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xubuntu-desktop) package to see the difference.